# How to play song again after stop it in android?

Tags: android

**Hello Friends,
I make one app in android, in which i take three radio button in radiogroup and take two buttons "play" and "stop".
my problem is that when i play the song it is playing well but when i click on stop button and then click on play button then song is not playing,
how to do that ? please help me if anybody know.
below is code that i write:**

```
 package com.mediaplayer;

import java.io.IOException;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class MediaplayerActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

MediaPlayer song1,song2,song3;
int whatsong = 0;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    RadioGroup rgMusic = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);

    song1 = MediaPlayer.create(MediaplayerActivity.this, R.raw.fluet);
    song2 = MediaPlayer.create(MediaplayerActivity.this, R.raw.mogra_na_phool);
    song3 = MediaPlayer.create(MediaplayerActivity.this, R.raw.airtel);


    Button bPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
    Button bStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStop);

    rgMusic.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    bPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {           

            if(song1.isPlaying())
            {
                song1.pause();
                song1.seekTo(0);
            }

            if(song2.isPlaying())
            {
                song2.pause();
                song2.seekTo(0);
            }

            if(song3.isPlaying())
            {
                song3.pause();
                song3.seekTo(0);
            }

            switch (whatsong) {

            case 1:
                try {
                    song1.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {                 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {                   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                song1.start();
                break;  

            case 2:
                try {
                    song2.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {                 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {                   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                song2.start();
                break;

            case 3:
                try {
                    song3.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {                     
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {               
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                song3.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    bStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       

            switch (whatsong) {

            case 1:
                song1.stop();
                break;  

            case 2:
                song2.stop();
                break;

            case 3:
                song3.stop();
                break;
            }           
        }
    });                                      
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int rbId) {      

    switch (rbId) {
    case R.id.rbMusic1:
        whatsong = 1;           
        break;
    case R.id.rbMusic2:
        whatsong = 2;           
        break;
    case R.id.rbMusic3:
        whatsong = 3;           
        break;

    }

}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

now use this edited code. This code will help you. If it is not running properly inform me.

```
package com.mediaplayer;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.media.MediaPlayer;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.RadioGroup;
import android.widget.RadioGroup.OnCheckedChangeListener;

public class MediaplayerActivity extends Activity implements OnCheckedChangeListener {

MediaPlayer song1;
int whatsong = 0;

private ArrayList<Integer> songIds;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);



    RadioGroup rgMusic = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);


    songIds=new ArrayList<Integer>();

    songIds.add(R.raw.fluet);
    songIds.add(R.raw.mogra_na_phool);
    songIds.add(R.raw.airtel);

    song1 = MediaPlayer.create(Nothing.this, R.raw.fluet);


    Button bPlay = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bPlay);
    Button bStop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bStop);

    rgMusic.setOnCheckedChangeListener(this);

    bPlay.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {           



            if(song1!=null)
            {
               song1.release();
            }


            switch (whatsong) {

            case 1:
                try {
                    song1 = MediaPlayer.create(Nothing.this, songIds.get(0));
                    song1.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {                 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {                   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                song1.start();
                break;  

            case 2:
                try {
                    song1 = MediaPlayer.create(Nothing.this, songIds.get(1));
                    song1.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {                 
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {                   
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                song1.start();
                break;

            case 3:
                try {
                    song1 = MediaPlayer.create(Nothing.this, songIds.get(2));
                    song1.prepare();
                } catch (IllegalStateException e) {                     
                    e.printStackTrace();
                } catch (IOException e) {               
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                song1.start();
                break;
            }
        }
    });

    bStop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {       

           if(song1!=null){
               song1.release();
           }
        }
    });                                      
}

@Override
public void onCheckedChanged(RadioGroup group, int rbId) {      

    switch (rbId) {
    case R.id.rbMusic1:
        whatsong = 1;           
        break;
    case R.id.rbMusic2:
        whatsong = 2;           
        break;
    case R.id.rbMusic3:
        whatsong = 3;           
        break;

    }

}

}
```

Comment: thanks for answering Ilango.

as u told me to insert song.release() after song.stop() , I tried 

with that one also, but it gives me error (The application 

MediaPlayer has stopped unexpectedly) and i read from 

developer.android.com that if we release the song then it wiil 

go into END state and there is no way to start song again from 

END state.

so please give me another solution.

thanks again.

Comment: Thnak you very much Ilango,

I got solution of my problem.

Your given code is completely working.

thanks a lot again.

Comment: Hey Ilango, you just release the song when stop button is clicked, and you again create and prepare the song when again play button is clicked, but is there any way without releasing and creating the song we can perform same thing ?

Comment: hi after you played a media file and if you want to play another file before that you have to release media player. this is a good practice when u play a media file. For more information refer this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html#release%28%29.  if the above code is worked fine then accept this answer, by doing this others will make use this code. thanks

Comment: yes, I only accept your answer, other answer is not correct so i accept your answer, but i just want to know that is there any way without releasing and crearing the song we can perform same thing, becoz if we create all time when play button is clicked then it will take more time to execute the program, its affect the speed , thats why i m asking for this second way.

Answer (score 0):

this problem is raise because you just detect whether song is play ? but you have also detect with true or false ?

like ::

```
if(song1.isPlaying()==true)
 {
    song1.pause(); //or
    song1.stop():
 }
 else{
       song1.start();
     }
```

## Update

for pausing the mediaplayer i used...

```
Mediaplayer.pause();
length=Mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
```

and for resuming the player from the position wer it stopped lately is by......

```
Mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
Mediaplayer.start();
```

Comment: thanks for answering nik,

@nik 

if(song1.isPlaying()==true) is same as if(song1.isPlaying()) 

and you noticed that i write that code on bPlay (play button) 

onclick event and you telling me that song1.stop();

I dont want to stop song in bPlay event, for stop the playing 

song i write code of onclick event in bStop (Stop Button).

and that code is not problem. i request you to make one 

android example and run it and then tell me.

Comment: your answer is not helpful to me, but thanks for a giving answer.

Comment: first thing there is no "push" method for mediaplayer and there is also no "resume" method for mediaplayer in android,   please give me appropriate answer, just dont imagine and giving answer

Comment: hai jayesh there are also one way to do this that is :: you can mute sond at some button and when you click it will unmute

Comment: no i dont want to use mute and unmute here, i just want to play ,pause and again play song without create every time and release every time, is there any way for that ?

Comment: your code is right, but i have one problem that is how can we find that the song is in pause state, means by coding how we know that the song is in pause state

like if we want to know that the song is in started state then we use mediaplayer.isPlaying() as this what is for pause ?

Comment: suppose your duration maximum is 100 and minimum is 0 then if(duration is 0 or lower) then {}else{}

Answer (score 0):

for pausing and resuming media player you use this. i think it helped you.

```
if(song1.isPlaying()==true)
{
   Mediaplayer.pause();
   length=Mediaplayer.getCurrentPosition();
}

else
{
  Mediaplayer.seekTo(length);
  Mediaplayer.start();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
         mp.stop();
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.seekTo(0);
```